# Discrete function approximated by continuous function * dt

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If we have a discrete function $f_d(x)$ and continuous version $f_c(x)$, why is $f_d(x) \approx f_c(x) * dt$ ?

[image]

Specifically, if you look at the picture above, when you plugin integers into the continuous $y=x^2$ it is exactly equal to the discrete $y=x^2$. I don't see a $dt$ coming out anywhere.

Comment: Where did this idea about dt come from? Without any context this doesn't make much sense. The source for your picture (mathbitsnotebook.com?) Doesn't mention it at all?

Comment: https://youtu.be/UZpLHlDV4gA?t=1424

Comment: The font is kind of bad, but towards the bottom of the chalkboard you see he equates l_d(x, u) = l_c(x, u) dt

Comment: where subscript d just denotes a discrete version of function l and subscript c denotes the continuous version of function l

Comment: Ah no, thats not quite what he's written. He wrote $x[n + 1] = f_d(x[n], u[n]) \approx x[n] +  dt * f_c(x[n], u[n])$. That second $x[n] + ...$ is important. I think what he's getting at is that you can approximate the function $f_d(x[n], ..)$ by $f_c(x[n], ..)$, which itself can be approximated as a linear function (essentially the tangent line to the curve), and as the time between readings ($dt$) goes to zero, this becomes more accurate.